# TypeScript Property 'push' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, typescript2.0

This is my code.
Actually i am developing app on ionicframework with firebase server. 
This is my provider file(firebase.js)

```
commentPost(key, comment) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.dataProvider.getComments(key).take(1).subscribe((comments) => {
            var comments = comments;

            if (!comments) {
                comments = [comment];
            } else {
                comments.push(comment);
            }

            // Add both users as friends.
            this.dataProvider.postComments(key).update(comments).then((success) => {
                resolve(true)
            }).catch((error) => {
                this.loadingProvider.hide();
                reject(false)
             });
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: `{}` means it is an object. `push` is available on arrays

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace a property, you have to use

```
comment['propertyName'] = newValue;
```

If you want to new object,
first you need to have arrays of object and then use `push` on it.
e.g.

```
array = [
{name: 'firstName', surname: 'secondName'},
{name: 'firstName1', surname: 'secondName2'}
]
```

then

```
array.push({name: 'firstName2', surname: 'secondName2'});
```